# Change datatype of a column from nvarchar(50) to datetime

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to convert a column (Scan_Start) which is in nvarchar(50) format to datetime format. the column contains values like '20190410183452', basically it is in yyyymmddhhmmss. I have tried the following commands but it does not work.

```
UPDATE TableA SET Scan_Start2= cast((SUBSTRING(Scan_Start,1,4) + '-' +                                SUBSTRING(Scan_Start,5,2) + '-' + 
                            SUBSTRING(Scan_Start,7,2) + ' ' + 
                            SUBSTRING(Scan_Start,9,2) + ':' + 
                            SUBSTRING(Scan_Start,11,2) + ':' + 
                            SUBSTRING(Scan_Start,13,2)) AS DATETIME)
                            from GSSC_July_Completed_AP_Test_Date;
```

This command throws the following error.

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Another command that I have tried:

```
update TableA set Scan_Start2 = convert(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(Scan_Start, 9, 0, ' '), 12, 0, ':'), 15, 0, ':'));
```

This command throws the following error

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 16
>   The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Would anyone be able to help me with this.

Comment: can you post some of your sample input data, on which you are getting this error. Although it is clear in error that you are converting some value which is not valid `datetime`.

Comment: Please consult the [reference docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which explain which formats SQL Server supports and how to tell the `convert` function which format it is looking for. Then use string manipulation to get it into the correct format - assuming your data is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

If your string always same length and format, you can apply following logic, in case any string not in expected format, you would see `NULL`:

```
Declare @String varchar (20) = '20190410183452';


select  TRY_CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(@String, 8) ) as ConvertedDate,
        (SUBSTRING(@String,9, 2)) as [Hours],
        (SUBSTRING(@String,11, 2)) as [Minutes],
        (SUBSTRING(@String,13, 2)) as [Seconds],

        DATEADD(SECOND, 
                CAST( (SUBSTRING(@String,13, 2)) AS INT),
                DATEADD(MINUTE, 
                        CAST ((SUBSTRING(@String,11, 2)) AS INT),
                        DATEADD(HOUR, 
                                CAST( (SUBSTRING(@String,9, 2)) AS INT),
                                TRY_CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(@String, 8) )
                                )
                        )
                ) as CovertedDatetime
```